# What's the proper way to override Rails ActiveRecord creation/deletion events in a subclass, such as after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, events, activerecord, overriding

I have a class hierarchy as follows:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create { |i|
    #do something
  }
end

class B < A
  after_create { |i|
    #do something else after what A did
  }
end
```

I want to have A's behavior performed in B when after_create is invoked, but I am not sure of the proper way to write the after_create method in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each callback you define will be called, in order. You don't have anything special to do to get the behavior you want. The syntax you used is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the superclass version of a method using "super," like this:

```
class B < A
  def after_create
    super
    #now do something else after what A did
  end
end
```

Comment: That's really useful. This and Francois's answer both work. Thanks for the answer.